# Flash CC - Draw letter animation

Tags: animation, adobe-flash

I am making a splash screen for a website I am making, and I want one of the letters to draw itself, then expand out into the whole word. I have the expanding part done, but I need to make the letter draw out first.

Animation:

http://goo.gl/jBFdal

I am aware of the masking technique, but I don't want to manually draw it. When I do this, it results in differently sized segments and appears choppy. I also want it to have an ease, which is difficult to do frame by frame. Is there a good method for doing this?

Here's an idea of what I mean:

http://greensock.com/drawSVG

Comment: [You should avoid Flash](http://zachsaucier.com/blog/blog/2014/09/30/javascript-vs-flash/). There are [a lot of better ways](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39613/whats-the-best-way-to-animate-an-illustration-for-the-web/39665#39665) to create something like this on the modern web.

Comment: Also, both of your goo.gl links are broken

Comment: That won't work on any phone or computer that blocks Flash. You should still use another method, Flash is bad

Comment: What would you suggest use instead?

Comment: Read the links I posted before, you'll find your answer :)