# Easiest way to create animated icons

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I Am complete newbie in designing and have Came across the gif like https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES2Ta.jpg .. I want to know How to easily do this kinda of cool animation,What is the right tool to do it.

Right now Idea I have is create different thumbnails in photoshop and merge it as gif. OR is there any easiest way or tutorial.Some one guide me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion based because it varies depending on who's making it, the level of responsiveness, and other factors. [This answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39613/whats-the-best-way-to-animate-an-illustration-for-the-web/39665#39665) can likely give you some direction

Comment: Fireworks is actually better at this than Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

I create my animated gif's/preloaders with After Effects, because of the great animation tools and such.

After I created the animation I render it out as an image sequence, bring that into photoshop. After I set up my timeline correctly I choose save for web and then select gif and check animation.

To make it easy check this website, wich is an online editor for CSS3 animations. Wich is useful when you want to use it on a website.

http://cssanimate.com/