# Moden era GIF replacment in photoshop?

Tags: png, animation, gif

I have a created a small GIF consisting of 7 frames using photoshop CS 4.

Unfortunally, my GIF contains alpha/transparency and only after the fact did i realize the whole alpha / color palete problem with GIFs, so my animation is looking really bad now.

Im looking for some kind of way to combine the animation of a GIF with the innate abilities of a PNG file if possible. However, i was unable to find something so far. 
Can someone advice me ?

Comment: Depends on where you want to display your image. In if in a browser then just put the frames side by side anda nimate with css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [APNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) (Animated PNG) format, which has actually been around for a long time. Browser support is patchy at best though and support in image editing programs is even worse. APNG is an unofficial extension to PNG and was officially rejected by the PNG group.

You can see some examples of animated PNGs here (you'll need to make sure you're using a browser that supports APNGs):

- https://people.mozilla.org/~dolske/apng/demo.html

Since support is so limited you're probably better off sticking to your animated GIF than using APNG though. There are a number of other, probably better, options for animations on the web. You can do a lot with CSS animations and even more with SVG and CSS (and Javascript for more complex animations). You can even use a sprite sheet of regular PNGs and create your animation from that using CSS.

Some more in-depth explanations of web animations can be found here:

- [What's the best way to animate an illustration for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/39613/52050)
- [How do you animate SVG for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68314/how-do-you-animate-svg-for-the-web)