# Relative coordinates in animateMotion path

Tags: svg, path, animation, html

I cannot figure out why the blue ball1 in the following example does not "move to" the point on the path specified in #wire from its starting positions to mimic the path animation of the pink ball2. The ball1 element animation follows the path relative to its initial position by adding M x,y rather than absolutely moving to M x,y first. What gives?

```html
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle
     cx="100"
     cy="20"
     r="8"
     id="ball1"
     style="fill:#529fd9">
    <animateMotion
       begin="4s"
       dur="4s"
       repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath
         xlink:href="#wire" />
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <circle
     cx="0"
     cy="0"
     r="8"
     id="ball2"
     style="fill:#FF00FF">
    <animateMotion
       begin="2s"
       dur="4s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       path="M 30.3614137,34.984057 H 91.361414 c 0,0 96.336296,1.512455 96.336296,11.762456 0,10.25 -96.086296,11.737544 -96.086296,11.737544 h -43.5 c 0,0 -10.75,0.75 -11.75,11.5 -1,10.75 9.75,12.25 9.75,12.25 H 352.86141">
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
    <path
     d="M 30.3614137,34.984057 H 91.361414 c 0,0 96.336296,1.512455 96.336296,11.762456 0,10.25 -96.086296,11.737544 -96.086296,11.737544 h -43.5 c 0,0 -10.75,0.75 -11.75,11.5 -1,10.75 9.75,12.25 9.75,12.25 H 352.86141"
     id="wire"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#529fd9;stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: In general, [you should avoid SMIL animations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/68322/23061).

Answer (score 0):

It does not move to the start location because that's simply not how it is works. If you need to compensate for offset the `cx` and `cy` you could add a `transform`. Or just remove them.

In general [you should avoid SMIL animations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/68322/23061). Using alternative methods of animating that have better support (such as GSAP's motion path functionality) will be easier to use as well as have better browser support.