# Export svg with animations using Adobe Animate

Tags: svg, adobe-animate

I have created a simply Sun animation and for now, I want to export my whole 2s animation into SVG file that could be later imported into the React project as an SVG file that contains my all animations inside SVG code. I am creating a canvas file and when I want to export or publish this I can only export SVG IMAGE that does not contain any animations. How to properly use Adobe Animate to later export SVG with animations that could be later imported into the React project?

Comment: Check this link from Adobe: [Export SVG animations for the web with snap svg](https://theblog.adobe.com/export-svg-animations-for-the-web-with-snap-svg/)

Comment: I think [using Adobe's own docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html#Merge_JSON_data) is more useful.

Comment: Also related: [How do you animate SVG for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/68322/23061)

Answer (score -1):

found this
https://nipunasthana.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/export-svg-sequence/

release link is dead, so i found this:

https://github.com/TomByrne/Flash2Svg/releases

Installed on adobe animate cc 2017 but it drops me an error when exporting animated svg

doNextTimeline: 0 file:///Macintosh%20HD/Users/JCS/Dropbox/Tipsr/test/test.fla.svg
getShape:  (Timeline Scene 1, Layer Layer 1, Frame 0, EditPath 0)
Error: 'moveSelectionBy' requires a selection.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Thank you for contributing, but please don't leave link only answers as links have a tendency to rot over time. If you do want to answer then you should really mention what is at those links, and how they will help solve the OP's problem.