# How to create animation with svg format file?

Tags: svg, animation, adobe-after-effects

How to create svg animation like this?
https://cl.parspack.com/clients/templates/ps_seven/img/svg/header.svg

I search on google but I can't any way to create animation with `svg` format file like this. Adobe After Effects, Adobe Animate and Adobe Edge Animate can't export file by `svg` format for animation!!

Comment: The link says I'm "not authorized" to view the svg.

Comment: @Wolff link was update.

Comment: @mods: can we merge this Q (because of the updated answer) to this older dupe? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68314/how-do-you-animate-svg-for-the-web

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the svg you link to is animated using *CSS Animations*. Read about it on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/).

Inspecting the moving elements with browser *Developer Tools* by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> is revealing:

[image]

These animations could be hand coded by editing the SVG file in a text editor. But the source code contains tons of animation keyframes.

[image]

This seems like too much work to do manually. It must have been generated by some kind of SVG animating software.

[Searching Google for "svg animation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=svg+animation) gives a lot of results. For example the first on my list: [svgator](https://www.svgator.com/), which seems to be a paid application which enables you to make SVG animations in a graphical interface without coding. There might be free alternatives too, although I couldn't find any which didn't require coding.

*To my knowledge* (please correct me if I'm wrong) none of Adobe's applications are capable of exporting SVG animations. The closest thing i found is [this](https://theblog.adobe.com/export-svg-animations-for-the-web-with-snap-svg) plugin for Adobe Animate, but sadly it seems to be discontinued.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But not any application like adobe apps for design animation with svg format file? Because create animation by codding is very time consuming.

Comment: Did a little more googling. See my update.

Comment: I used Adobe Animate `https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/exporting-svg-format.html` before but with this way, it just export svg from first frame!

Comment: Just played around with Animate and you are right. I should keep my mouth shut about things I'm not sure about, sorry. 

Comment: No dear friend. Thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

SVG files can have declarations for class and/or IDs.

That file is merely using the animation [ability of Cascading Style Sheets v3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) (CSS3) to introduce animation based upon various IDs.

```
#el_hAVKZVGCL * {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1); }
```

And...

```
#el_DFuNmafRaa_an_QQ_Jhl6Ej {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    -webkit-transform: translate(285.1300048828125px, 387.6100158691406px) translate(-285.1300048828125px, -387.6100158691406px) translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(285.1300048828125px, 387.6100158691406px) translate(-285.1300048828125px, -387.6100158691406px) translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-animation-name: kf_el_DFuNmafRaa_an_QQ_Jhl6Ej;
    animation-name: kf_el_DFuNmafRaa_an_QQ_Jhl6Ej;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

This is all done via CSS. Whether or not you can use an Adobe app to generate the proper CSS is another matter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But not any application like adobe apps for design animation with `svg` format file? Because create animation by codding is very time consuming.

Comment: Adobe Animate focuses on **canvas** animations, not CSS animations. And After Effects focuses on **video** (obviously). To the best of my knowledge neither After Effects nor Animate will export CSS animations. They have to be *created* via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott mentioned, Adobe Animate focuses on canvas animations, not CSS, and AE on video. As far as I know, there are certain plugins that you can use to force the export of an SVG file, but it isn't exactly the best solution. I haven't tried them out yet.

I prefer to use SVGator if I need a single SVG file and there's no Adobe product that would allow you to set interactivity like Animate on mouseover, on click, and so on.