# How to make my animated SVG CLI-like typewriter effect work as intended? (SMIL)

Tags: svg, animation, css, xml

I am just starting to learn to do SVG Animations, and I'm trying to make a command-line style 'typewriter' effect, typing out several different lines of text, one after the other.

I would like the finished animation to do the following:

1. Show a prompt with a blinking Full Block cursor, blinking 3 times. *(fig. 1)*
2. Type out a line of text, letter by letter, with the cursor following at the end (not blinking) like an actual CLI. *(fig. 2 but with cursor following)*
3. Show the full line with the cursor at the end, blinking 3 times immediately after the full line is typed out.
4. 'Delete' the line, letter by letter. *(fig. 3 but cursor following)*
5. Repeat with a different line of text, and so forth.

Fig. 4 is what I have so far, but as you can see, there are a couple of problems:

1. No following cursor.
2. There's a pause after the line is fully typed and before the cursor starts blinking. Also after having blinked, before starting the 'delete' part.
3. It seems that there's a slight apparent movement of the text, when hiding the typed out text and simultaneously showing the text used for the 'delete' part.
4. I haven't figured out how to conveniently make the whole animation loop with different lines of text. I have tried to just copy-paste it and change `id` attributes, but the XML is getting very large and confusing, so I haven't had any luck.

**Fig. 1:**

```xml
<svg
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
    viewBox='0 0 1152 50'
    style='background-color: #000000;'
    width='1152px' height='50px'>

    <!-- Show prompt -->
    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
        dominant-baseline='middle' x='0%' y='21' text-anchor='start'>
        <!-- 1 non-breaking space followed by '❯' -->
        &#160;&#10095;

    </text>
    
    <!-- Blink cursor -->
    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
        dominant-baseline='middle' x='0%' y='21' text-anchor='start'>
        <!-- 3 non-breaking spaces followed by '█' -->
        &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#x2588;

        <animate id="blinker" attributeName="opacity" dur="1s" values="1;0" repeatCount="3" begin="0s" calcMode="discrete"/>
        <set attributeName="opacity" to="0" begin="blinker.end"></set>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ja0x5rs8/

**Fig. 2:**

```xml
<svg
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
    viewBox='0 0 1152 50'
    style='background-color: #000000;'
    width='1152px' height='50px'>
    <style>
        @font-face {
        font-family: 'Inconsolata';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-display: fallback;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Show prompt -->
    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
        dominant-baseline='middle' x='0%' y='21' text-anchor='start'>
        <!-- 1 non-breaking space followed by '❯' -->
        &#160;&#10095;

    </text>    

    <path id='typer_path'>
        <animate id='d1' attributeName='d' begin='0s'
                        dur='3500ms' fill='remove'
                        values='m0,25 h0; m0,25 h1152'
                        keyTimes='0; 1' />
    </path>
    
    
    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
            dominant-baseline='middle'
            x='0%' text-anchor='start'>
    
        <animate id="show1" attributeName="opacity" values="100" begin="0s" dur="500" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
    
        <textPath xlink:href='#typer_path'>
                &#xa0;&#xa0; hashcat -m 0 511c04a3d19150f1903ef5b92d748a65 -a 3 -1 aeiou -2 bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz &#039;?1?2?1?2?s?d?d?d?d&#039; -w 4 -O&#x2588;
    
            </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u3ypnwrm/

**Fig. 3:**

```xml
<svg
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
    viewBox='0 0 1152 50'
    style='background-color: #000000;'
    width='1152px' height='50px'>
    <style>
        @font-face {
        font-family: 'Inconsolata';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-display: fallback;
        }
    </style>
    
    <!-- Show prompt -->
    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
        dominant-baseline='middle' x='0%' y='21' text-anchor='start'>
        <!-- 1 non-breaking space followed by '❯' -->
        &#160;&#10095;

    </text>

    <path id='typer_path'>
        <animate id='d1' attributeName='d' begin='0s'
                        dur='1500ms' fill='remove'
                        values='m0,25 h1152; m0,25 h0'
                        keyTimes='0; 1' />
    </path>
    
    
    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
            dominant-baseline='middle'
            x='0%' text-anchor='start'>
    
        <animate id="show1" attributeName="opacity" values="100" begin="0s" dur="500" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
    
        <textPath xlink:href='#typer_path'>
                &#xa0;&#x276f; hashcat -m 0 511c04a3d19150f1903ef5b92d748a65 -a 3 -1 aeiou -2 bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz &#039;?1?2?1?2?s?d?d?d?d&#039; -w 4 -O&#x2588;
    
            </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L0tdsu1w/

**Fig. 4:**

```xml
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
    viewBox='0 0 1152 50'
    style='background-color: #000000;'
    width='1152px' height='50px'>


    <!-- PROMPT START -->
    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
            dominant-baseline='middle' x='0%' y='21' text-anchor='start'>
            <!-- 1 non-breaking space followed by '❯' -->
            &#xa0;&#x276f;

        </text>
    <!-- PROMPT END -->

    <!-- CURSOR BLINK START -->
        <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
            dominant-baseline='middle' x='0%' y='21' text-anchor='start'>
            <!-- 3 non-breaking spaces followed by '█' -->
            &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#x2588;

            <animate id="blinker" attributeName="opacity" dur="1s" values="1;0" repeatCount="3" begin="0s" calcMode="discrete"/>
            <set attributeName="opacity" to="0" begin="blinker.end"></set>
        </text>
    <!-- CURSOR BLINK END -->



    <!-- TYPER START -->
    <path id='path0'>
        <animate id='d1' attributeName='d' begin='blinker.end'
                        dur='3500ms' fill='remove'
                        values='m0,25 h0 ; m0,25 h1152' keyTimes='0; 1' />
    </path>


    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
            dominant-baseline='middle'
            x='0%' text-anchor='start'>

        <animate id="show" attributeName="opacity" values="100" begin="blinker.end" dur="500" calcMode="discrete"></animate>

        <textPath xlink:href='#path0'>
                &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;hashcat -m 0 511c04a3d19150f1903ef5b92d748a65 -a 3 -1 aeiou -2 bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz &#039;?1?2?1?2?s?d?d?d?d&#039; -w 4 -O█

            </textPath>
    </text>
    <!-- TYPER END -->


    <!-- POST PROMPT START -->
    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14' opacity="0"
            dominant-baseline='middle' x='0%' y='21' text-anchor='start'>

            &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;hashcat -m 0 511c04a3d19150f1903ef5b92d748a65 -a 3 -1 aeiou -2 bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz &#039;?1?2?1?2?s?d?d?d?d&#039; -w 4 -O

            <animate id="post_hider" attributeName="opacity" dur="1s" values="0;1" repeatCount="3" begin="d1.end" calcMode="discrete"/>
        </text>
    <!-- POST PROMPT END -->


    <!-- POST CURSOR BLINK START -->
        <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14' opacity="0"
            dominant-baseline='middle' x='0%' y='21' text-anchor='start'>

            &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;hashcat -m 0 511c04a3d19150f1903ef5b92d748a65 -a 3 -1 aeiou -2 bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz &#039;?1?2?1?2?s?d?d?d?d&#039; -w 4 -O█

            <animate id="post_blinker" attributeName="opacity" dur="1s" values="1;0" repeatCount="3" begin="d1.end" calcMode="discrete"/>
            <set attributeName="opacity" to="0" begin="post_blinker.end"></set>
        </text>
    <!-- POST CURSOR BLINK END -->



    <!-- DELETER START -->
    <path id='path1'>
        <animate id='d1_1' attributeName='d' begin='post_blinker.end'
                        dur='3500ms' fill='remove'
                        values='m0,25 h1152; m0,25 h0' keyTimes='0; 1' />
    </path>


    <text font-family='"Inconsolata", monospace' fill='#126D08' font-size='14'
            dominant-baseline='middle'
            x='0%' text-anchor='start'>

        <animate id="show_1" attributeName="opacity" values="100" begin="post_blinker.end" dur="500" calcMode="discrete"></animate>

        <textPath xlink:href='#path1'>
            &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;hashcat -m 0 511c04a3d19150f1903ef5b92d748a65 -a 3 -1 aeiou -2 bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz &#039;?1?2?1?2?s?d?d?d?d&#039; -w 4 -O█

            </textPath>
    </text>
    <!-- DELETER END -->

</svg>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1aub6dqs/

Comment: i think smil is pretty much deprecated

Comment: Relevant: [How do you animate SVG for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/68322/23061)

Comment: You might want to check out [termtosvg](https://nbedos.github.io/termtosvg/index.html) which lets you record your terminal to an animated SVG automatically.