# Export to vector format from After Effects

Tags: vector, export, adobe-after-effects, adobe-flash

I would like to export some simple vector animations created with After Effects, and keep the animation in a vector form, such as the Flash format.
I am using After Effects CC and it seems that there is no built-in export procedure to do so. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can export to the vector format SVG using an AfterEffects plugin called [Bodymovin](https://github.com/bodymovin/bodymovin). It has some limitations, but is a very useful plugin.

If you really want to export to Flash, export to SWF format. Though you may run into some issues doing that, so looking at a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/gmVZYRGzhYU?t=5m27s) may help.

Comment: Do you know how to export to Flash in AE CC?

Comment: @MicroMachine You don't want to export to flash. See [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/39665/23061) for more info.

Comment: This is not solved then? I thought it implied AE can output a SWF still (or Adobe Media Encoder?...)

Comment: @MicroMachine I haven't tried to, but you can look in the linked video or other resources for how to do so. What I'm saying is that you *shouldn't* :P