# Bodymovin a good idea for web animations?

Tags: website-design, animation, adobe-after-effects

On our new "how it works" page we want to use animated graphics to better explain some concepts of our service. We don't have any experience with more complex animations and we decided to try Bodymovin, as creating the animations in After Effects  saves valuable dev ressources.
However, some of the visual elements will need to change their size and layout, depending on the viewport.

Now we wonder, if Bodymovin is the right choice: Is it possible to somehow access the SVG and change those properties while keeping the animation intact? Or do we need a (slightly) different SVG for each viewport, each with its own Bodymovin json animation file? Because in this case this page is going to be huge ...

In general: If you have any suggestions, best practices, life examples of Bodymovin, I'd be very grateful to check those out.

Comment: Isn't this a question for BodyMov support?

Comment: Idk, is there something like Bodymovin support? After all, it's just an AE extension ... but I will check. My hope was, that someone else had this problem already and solved it. Or at least can answer my question.

Comment: This definitely is more of a support question than a design question. You better ask the plugin developers instead of us: https://aescripts.com/bodymovin/

Comment: This is a "real product"-question: I'm searching for people, who tried Bodymovin and have experience with it. That's "product design".

Comment: See [What's the best way to animate an illustration for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/39665/23061)

Comment: "general advice on bodymovin" is too broad of a request for a Q&A sure site like GD. Yes Bodymovin can be responsive if you do it right. It may not be the best choice. See the above comment to help you think through your options

Comment: You think asking for real life experience with Bodymovin in regards of my 2, 3 specific questions is too broad, but you link to a question that's literally "What's the best way to animate an illustration for the web"?? :D But thanks for the link, this looks like a great overview. Btw ... we went with GSAP.

Comment: @fgrau the linked question at least had an example of something they were trying to illustrate, but I more or less agree with you that it's a bit broad

Answer (score 1):

Bodymovin is the best you would find if you are looking to animate simple or even complex animations. It doesn't need much dev work, the pluging itself has a render option which allows you to spit out the code, even .json code to use it in IOS apps or also android apps.

But make sure your svg's don't have gradients. Lottie can't export **gradients** & **soft edges**

Here is the exports sheet

[image]

So yea give it a go.

Personally i used it for an onboarding for the Fox Sports NRL app

https://dribbble.com/shots/4162353-Onboarding-Animation

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. My question is, if I need multiple key visuals (and animations) for different viewports, if the smaller size of the viewports demands a layout change within those key visuals.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean by key visuals and viewpoints ? Can you link me an example what you want to create ?

Comment: The "viewport" is the visible area of a website within a browser window; with "key visuals" I mean some kind of graphic element that is placed on the website.

Take any product page on Dribbble with the usual alternating "text left - image right" layout: When it's a responsive site and the viewport gets narrower, the images don't have as much space anymore and need to change.

Comment: Ah right, got ya!  Google Web Designer is what you are looking for, it detect automatically that. Wheres Bodymovin is just the size you create and the viewpoint doesn't change.

Answer (score -1):

There is another great tool that could cover all your needs. I mean [Google Web Designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/).

With thi tool you can build

- responisve layouts
- use components
- call events
- use multiple pages
- animate in 2D and 3D

and a lot of more. Definitely you should try this tool.

Comment: And I forgot: You can use Media Rules that's suits your question about viewports.

Comment: Seems to be more an advertisement than a solution for the given question ...