# What replaced Flash?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, adobe-flash

Years ago, I used to make animations and cartoons and stuff using Flash, back when it was Macromedia, before Adobe bought them out.

Shortly afterwards my career took a different path entirely and I've not looked at anything like this since... I really want to start doing some fun stuff again, more as a hobby than anything else; life is too serious these days.

So I was wondering what is the standard these days?

I understand Flash is dead/dying so something must have replaced it - what is that something?

Comment: You should check out [What's the best way to animate an illustration for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/39665/23061)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adobe Flash became [**Adobe Animate**](https://www.adobe.com/products/animate.html).

Whether or not that fills your needs is impossible for me to say.

There are other things out there but they all depend on what *specifically* you want to create. Many 3D applications are capable of animation. And there are products specifically designed to animate things like user interfaces as well.