# After Effcets JPEG vs PNG Sequence

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I am trying to get the still sequence of an AE animation by using AE render.

I want the output on a transparent background (Channels RGB+Alpha) and on the drop down I see both JPEG and PNG sequence.

Do you know what is the difference between these two? What is the best sequence to adopt for a GIF to be rendered on a browser? which format is the fastest for the browser?

[image: settings]

Comment: JPEG has no support for alpha transparency.

Comment: Okay. What if you the transparency dimension is not involved. What would be better for browser in terms of speed without destroying the quality.

Comment: If you are ultimately converting it into a GIF, then it won't make any difference to how quickly a browser will play the GIF. But there will be no transparency in a GIF made from a JPEG sequence, unless you manually remove the background in each frame of the animation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I.** If it is a flat style motion graphics I would not use JPG (Or any compressed video format) to prepare an animated gif. Use PNG.

The reason is that there is a chance, due the JPG compression, that flat color areas create some compression artifacts, which basically is a slight variation of color. This could confuse the next program at the moment where it chooses the color palette for the Animated Gif.

**II.** Animated GIF does not support alpha transparency. You can choose 1 color of the color palette, to be transparent. You could use the color on the top-left pixel.

**III.** The fastest is relative. A small animated GIF with no dither, with only some frames, is a good idea. But some other animations will be better served as Mp4 video or CSS animation. Take a look at some options [Creating high quality animated backgrounds from Illustrator files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121859/creating-high-quality-animated-backgrounds-from-illustrator-files/121890#121890)

Comment: thanks for your time and answer. Used PNG.

Comment: I personally go by the following rule. Because disk space costs less than my daily salary any file that is for me to work with should be lossless since there is allways a off chance that that will cause problems later. Any such problem would cost me more than the disk space so not worth it. Customer facing files on the otherhand are not master files, will never be the primary archive. These should always be compressed as well as i possibly can do in my time budget.