# Animated Gif on Gimp with Drop Shadows

Tags: inkscape, gimp, gif, animated-gif

**Briefly:**
First time making an animated GIF, I would like to create the GIF with drop shadows. However, the output of GIF exports has no more drop shadows.

**Details:**
I created 6 frames on Inkscape, each with their respective drop shadow. Then exported each as PNG.

[image]

Next I imported each frame as a layer in a new GIMP file, and used the Filter>Animation>Playback to make the necessary adjustments. (At that point the drop shadows are no longer visible).

[image]

Finally I exported the file as animated GIF, and drop shadows are no longer visible. See output:

[image]

**Attempts:**

Honestly I haven't seen any options on GIMP that seemed to be related to this. What can be done to get the shadows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem here is not with Gimp, it's with GIF. GIF does not support partial transparency.

If you must use a GIF file then your only options are no drop shadows, or having a solid background behind the animation so partial transparency is not needed.

You could possibly use small dots instead of a gradient to get a less than perfect alternative to partial transparency.

If you intend to use this on the web. You can possibly use PNG files animated with CSS as a sprite animation (sprites are also the way to go if you need to use this in a game).

More on animated images on the web detailed under [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39613/whats-the-best-way-to-animate-an-illustration-for-the-web) question

Comment: Or APNG could be an option - I didn't see it mentioned in the linked post.