# Methods of loading icons for wordpres?

Tags: website-design, icon

I'd like to add an animation I made as a loading icon for a wordpress site, but I'm not sure what method most efficiently accomplishes this. Is it better to use a built-in algorithm of the site that renders vectors or is it better to use a PNG animation that I import? Or is there a different method? A loading icon might require adding some kind of extra script in HTML5 or JS but I'm not sure what route to take.

Not for a larger flash animation, but specifically for a loading icon. Is it more efficient to make one using vectors and algorithms to make a loading icon, or to implement an imported loading icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to animate an illustration for the web?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39613/whats-the-best-way-to-animate-an-illustration-for-the-web)

Comment: I'm unclear if you are asking how to make an animation.. or how to implement an animation into Wordpress.

Comment: It's unclear because I am asking about both, and not for a larger flash animation, but specifically for a loading icon, as stated in the question. Is it more efficient to make one using vectors and algorithms or to implement an imported one, as stated in the question.

Comment: What to use depends completely on the sort of loading animation that you want to do and what you have skills in making. Sorry, but this question is way too broad for the StackExchange network.

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient method of animating something like a loading icon may be to create it with [**pure Cascading Style Sheets**](https://loading.io/css/). There are no images to load and the http request is typically the same as when loading the basic page display.

Secondly, may be a small animated **gif** because the format supports animation and there's little to no overhead in terms of scripting. Searching the web, there are many, many [tutorials](https://medialoot.com/blog/loading-animation-tutorial/) ([2](https://www.toptal.com/designers/product-design/how-to-create-custom-loading-animations-to-decrease-bounce-rates), [3](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/how-to-create-animated-gif-quick-tip-ht)) to create such an image. As well as places you can merely [download an existing animation](https://icons8.com/preloaders/) ([1](https://loading.io/spinner/download/-download-arrow-circle-slide), [2](https://giphy.com/explore/loading)) for use.

As for *how* to implement such a thing for Wordpress, that's off topic here and better handled at [Wordpress.StackExchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) if not [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com).